# Error in configuring ffmpeg in Windows 8 , 5.3 PHP

Tags: xampp, windows-8.1, ffmpeg-php

I am trying to configure ffmpeg using this tutorial -
http://myownhomeserver.com/2012/12/how-to-install-ffmpeg-php-php-5-4-on-windows-8-xampp-1-8-1/
but after I had done initial configuration, it is throwing error.

I copied `php_ffmpeg.dll` in ext folder also added it in `php.ini` file `extension=php_ffmpeg.dll`
copied other files to `system32` folder. but it is throwing error while restarting apache. it is throwing below errow

```
---------------------------
httpd.exe - System Error
---------------------------
The program can't start because avcodec-52.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem. 
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

I can see that above tutorial was for PHP 5.4 and above so I found this tutorial http://myownhomeserver.com/2012/02/how-to-install-ffmpeg-php-for-windows-apache-http-server/

this is for PHP 5.3 but still it seems to show same error for me

I cant understand what went wrong can some help me please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the guide you are looking at it says that you need PHP 5.4 or higher. You should first have installed [PHP 5.4](http://windows.php.net/download/#php-5.4) and then to download the files from this [link](http://myownhomeserver.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/ffmpeg6-php54-win32-vc9-all.zip) and place `php_ffmpeg.dll` in `C:/xampp/php/ext` and the rest of the files in `C:/windows/system32`.

Also, if you are on **64-bit system** try to add the files that you placed in `C:/windows/system32` to be in `C:\Windows\SysWOW64` too.

Then go to your Xampp Services, and click on `stop` Apache. When its stopped, then click start again and it should work.

Comment: Hi cchacholiades, thanks for answer, I am using 64 bit system and  I forgot to copy files in `C:\Windows\SysWOW64`.After I had copied the files there. it is not throwing that error now also I checked the `phpinfo()` , it shows that ffmpeg is installed...thanks a lot